# How to close FileStream without causing an error in "Syncfusion.PdfViewer"?

Tags: c#, wpf, filestream, syncfusion

I'm using `Syncfusion.PdfViewer` in my project. When I click an item in a list, the related pdf file is loaded and shown in the `PdfViewer`:

```
private void PdfReport(string address)
{
    //Load the stream from the local system.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(address, FileMode.Open);
    PdfSource = fs;
}
```

The problem is that each time I load a pdf file, a new instance of `FileStream` is created and the memory usage increases. When I try to close `FileStream` like the following code, the pdf is not shown in the viewer:

```
private void PdfReport(string address)
{
    //Load the stream from the local system.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(address, FileMode.Open);
    PdfSource = fs;
    fs.Dispose();
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if a `PdfSource` exists and if so close/ dispose that *before* creating the new filestream, so just

```cs
if (PdfSource is not null)
    PdfSource.Dispose();

PdfSource = new FileStream(address, FileMode.Open);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Syncfusion PDFViewer, while loading the PDF document as stream/file, it unloads the existing loaded document internally. While unloading the document, it will dispose the file stream. Hence, we don’t need to dispose the file stream on the sample side.